# Getting crash while calling a function which need reference to vector

Tags: c++, stl

I want to know is there something wrong in passing in passing vector reference to a function as in the example below. This code is running well and nice. But the same type of code in my project gives me crash. I don't know why.

In that case whenever I calls the function which need std::vector & . then in the called function the size of the vector reaches some millionsss.... I have attached screenshot where I am actually getting this crash.
[image]
I just wants to know is there something wrong in these type of implementations...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    void GetVector(std::vector<std::wstring> &in) {
        std::wstring s = L"Hello";
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            in.push_back(s);
    }
};

class B {
public:
    B() {}
    ~B() {}

    void GetData() {
        A a;
        std::vector<std::wstring> s;
        a.GetVector(s);
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    b.GetData();

    return 0;
}
```

Real code where I am getting the crash...

```
void SCPreferenceComp::PopulateComboBox()
{
    SCConfig *config = SCConfig::GetInstance();
    std::vector<std::wstring> languages;
    config->GetAllLangugesName(languages);
    for(size_t i = 0; i != languages.size(); i++)
        mLangListComboBox->addItem(languages[i].c_str(), i+1);
    if(mLangListComboBox->getNumItems() > 0)
        mLangListComboBox->setSelectedId(1);
}

bool SCConfig::GetAllLangugesName(std::vector<std::wstring> &outLangNames)
{
    bool retVal = false;
    do
    {
        if(!mXMLDoc)
            break;
        xercesc::DOMNodeList *langNodeList = mXMLDoc->getElementsByTagName(strToX("language"));
        if(!langNodeList)
            break;
        const XMLSize_t langCount = langNodeList->getLength();
        for(XMLSize_t i = 0; i < langCount; i++)
        {
            xercesc::DOMNode *curLangNode = langNodeList->item(i);
            if(!curLangNode)
                continue;
            xercesc::DOMElement *curLangElem = dynamic_cast<xercesc::DOMElement*>(curLangNode);
            if(!curLangElem)
                continue;
            wxString s = strToW(curLangElem->getAttribute(strToX("name")));
            outLangNames.push_back(s.c_str());
        }
        retVal = true;
    }while(false);

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: You should not expect toy code with a 10 member vector to repro a problem that occurs with millions of members. Could you post the real code instead of that image?

Comment: The screenshot doesn’t show any useful information about the crash and the code you posted doesn’t have any errors in it.

Comment: That code doesn't crash. Try a full recompile, perhaps you're linking against something stale.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong in that implementation other than the fact that it doesn't have any visible end result which leads me to believe it may not exactly match your failing code.

Comment: Yes yes... It's just a dummy one!